# Inserting a value (evaluated in views.py) to database in views.py

Tags: python, django

Here is the models.py file:

```
class SoundFile(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # Date of creation
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Sound File')    # Name of the file during upload
    nameOnly = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='FILENAME') # Song Identifier without file extension
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='XXXXXXX') # Song Identifier without file extension
    fileSize = models.IntegerField(default=0) # File size in bytes
    uploaded_file_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='URL')  # file url
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_frames = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I need to alter 'score' in views.py as it is evaluated by a function in views.py only.

views.py:

```
from .models import SoundFile
def rnp(request, nameOnly, no_of_frames):
# ...
# nameOnly is unique to every row in the database
file = SoundFile.objects.get(nameOnly=nameOnly)

score = compare.evaluate(freq, freq_u)
# This doesn't work
file.score = score
# ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? What happens? Do you get an error? In any case, do you save that object anywhere?

Comment: You called `file.save()`?

Comment: @KlausD. It worked. Thanks!